# Forcing other phones to recognize update in bluetooth device name for android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am currently creating an Android app that requires using the Android phone's name to store information about the phone. So the name of the phone is always changing. However, the when other phones perform multiple Bluetooth scans, they always seem to only use the first name that was recognized by the phone, even after the phone name has changed. Is there a way to force an Android app to see the new name or flush some kind of cache everything the Bluetooth scan has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to manually clear the cache and then make sure to not pair the phones. When the phones aren't paired, the name isn't cached in the phone.

Comment: Is there a solution in Java ?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Howell's answer you can use setName to change the name, and you can use fetchUuuidsWithSdp() to force an update of the name of another phone, but I believe that there is no way for you to force another device to update the service information and name that it has for you.

I guess the best you can do is to simply create a new connection to it and hope that that triggers it to update the info it has on you, but even if that worked it would be implementation dependent (i.e. not reliable), because it has no need to.

Comment: This is the correct answer for when the phones are paired. I'm not going to pair my phones though. I just need to manually clear the cache and not pair the phones, therefore no information will be stored in the bluetooth adapter cache. Thanks for the response though. It led me to the right answer.

Comment: If you are planning to do Bluetooth comm without pairing then be fore-warned - there is a bug in Android 4...
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29039

Comment: I don't quite understand what they're the problem is Tom. Can you elaborate it a little simpler for me if you understand it please?

Comment: I think it boils down to this: you can't do insecure communication (e.g. do sockets between phones that are not paired) if one phone is pre-ICS and the other phone has ICS.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Tom. I'm just parsing out information based on the name of the phone though so I don't think that should affect me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.setName()` to set the name?

Comment: Yes, I use that to set the name. It seems the name is cached. After some research, I think it may involve the use of fetchUuidsWithSdp() but I can't figure out how to implement it.